# How to switch tabs in button click after saving data in mysql database in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am new to PHP, i started developing application using php, please look into my code

index.php

```
<?php require_once('./config.php'); ?>
<?php

/*
* Following code will get single product details
* A product is identified by product id (pid)
*/

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

$title = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];

require_once('./db_connect.php');

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(name,company) VALUES('$title','$company')");
}    

?>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        var tabContents = $(".tab_content").hide(),
        tabs = $("ul.tabs li");

        tabs.first().addClass("active").show();
        tabContents.first().show();
        tabs.click(function() {
        var $this = $(this), 
        activeTab = $this.find('a').attr('href');
        if(!$this.hasClass('active')){
        $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        tabContents.hide().filter(activeTab).fadeIn();
        }
        return false;
        });

        $(".tabbutton").click(function () {
            var nextTab = parseInt($("li.active").attr("id"), 10) + 1;
            if (nextTab === 4) { nextTab = 1; }
            tabs.removeClass("active");
             $("#" + nextTab).addClass("active");
             tabContents.hide();
             $("#tab" + nextTab).fadeIn("slow");                
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v1/"></script>
<!-- jQuery is used only for this example; it isn't required to use Stripe -->
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// this identifies your website in the createToken call below
Stripe.setPublishableKey("<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>");

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    if (response.error) {
        // re-enable the submit button
        $('.submit-button').removeAttr("disabled");
        // show the errors on the form
        $(".payment-errors").html(response.error.message);
    } else {
        var form$ = $("#payment-form");
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response['id'];
        // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "' />");
                // and submit
        form$.get(0).submit();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#payment-form").submit(function(event) {
        // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $('.submit-button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        // createToken returns immediately - the supplied callback submits the form if there are  no errors
        Stripe.createToken({
            number: $('.card-number').val(),
            cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
            exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
            exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
        }, stripeResponseHandler);
        return false; // submit from callback
    });
});
```

Body part

```
<ul class="tabs clearfix">
    <li id="1"><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li id="2"><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
    <li id="3"><a href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab_container">
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
        <form method="post">

            <p>
                    <label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name">

            </p>

            <p>
                    <label>Company:</label> <input type="text" name="company">
            </p>
           <input type="submit" value="SAVE" class="tabbutton"/>
    </form>

    </div>

<div id="tab2" class="tab_content"> 
     <form id="payment-form" action="charge.php" method="post">
<h3>Purchase a quote by Oscar Wilde today! Only $535! Limited supply and going fast, buy now!!</h3>
<!-- to display errors returned by createToken -->
<span class="payment-errors"></span>
<form action="charge.php" method="POST" id="payment-form">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Card Number</label>
            <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" class="card-number" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>CVC</label>
        <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" class="card-cvc" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
        <input type="text" size="2" class="card-expiry-month"/>
        <span> / </span>
        <input type="text" size="4" class="card-expiry-year"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Buy!</button>
</form>
</form>
</div>


<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
<p>Tab 3 Content Goes Here...</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In Tab1 I'm saving data into database. Whenever user clicks on the save button the data needs to be saved into database and it will go to Tab2. I am successful while saving the data. My problem is it is not going to Tab2 after saving the data. When we click on the save button, the tab2 is just blinking but the page is still showing tab1 content. I want that whenever the user clicks on the save button the data needs to be saved in database and it will go to Tab2 content.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try this approach, will solve your issue:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    tabs = $("ul.tabs li");
    tabs.first().addClass("active").show();
    $(".tab_content").first().show();

    tabs.click(function() {
        var $this = $(this), activeTab = $this.find('a').attr('href');
        if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
            $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            $(".tab_content").hide().filter(activeTab).fadeIn();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#tabbutton").click(function() {
        $("#2").addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        $("#tab2").fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="tabs clearfix">
        <li id="1"><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li id="2"><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
        <li id="3"><a href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
            <p>Tab 1 Content Goes Here...</p>
            <input type="button" id="tabbutton"/>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
            <p>Tab 2 Content Goes Here...</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
            <p>Tab 3 Content Goes Here...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

also you have couple of issues in your code.

first, you have added the form tag twice in your tab2 `div`. Remove one.

```
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content"> 
     <form id="payment-form" action="charge.php" method="post">
<h3>Purchase a quote by Oscar Wilde today! Only $535! Limited supply and going fast, buy now!!</h3>
<!-- to display errors returned by createToken -->
<span class="payment-errors"></span>
<form action="charge.php" method="POST" id="payment-form">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Card Number</label>
            <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" class="card-number" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>CVC</label>
        <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" class="card-cvc" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
        <input type="text" size="2" class="card-expiry-month"/>
        <span> / </span>
        <input type="text" size="4" class="card-expiry-year"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Buy!</button>
</form>
</form>
</div>
```

secondly, your tab3 `div` has the same id as tab1. i think this is causing the problem.
change it to tab3 and try.

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
<p>Tab 3 Content Goes Here...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @ahsan i did the things what u suggested , but no luck.

Comment: i have added new logic for tabbutton click. try this.

Comment: hi ahsan, i have tried the new logic but it is giving me the same result. no luck.

Comment: i have edited the answer for you and provided the working example. use the same approach.

Comment: hi ahsan , i tried ur approach , now the tab is changing from one to tab to another but the data is not inserting in database, when ever i change the input type=button to submit the reverse is working. ex: <input type="submit" id="tabbutton"/> in this case data insert is working , <input type="button" id="tabbutton"/> in this case tab switch is working.

Comment: give your form some id <form id="tab1Form" ...> and submit it in $("#tabbutton").click handler as follows: $('#tab1Form').submit();